# Module cannot be found when using "pythonw" (instead of "python") to run an application

Tags: python, macos, textmate, pythonw

I tried this minimal example:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

When I try `python hello.py`, everything goes well. However, when I try to run it from Textmate (Shift + Cmd + R) an error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/EventFeed/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Textmate calls `pythonw` instead of `python`. When I try `pythonw` myself the same error is thrown.

The `man pythonw` states that *As of Python 2.5, python and pythonw are interchangeable* though they appear not to be in this case.

Would you have an idea of what happens?

(Question [Code that works with python and not with pythonw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910012/code-that-works-with-python-and-not-with-pythonw) does not answer the question despite its similar title.)

Comment: Are you sure your `python` and `pythonw` are from the same Python installation? From the command line, run each one, then `import sys; print sys.executable, sys.path` and see what they say.

Comment: Wait a sec, this is a Mac, not Windows… just `which python` and `which pythonw` on the bash prompt will do it. And I'm 90% sure I already know what you're going to see, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `pythonw` and your `python` are not pointing at the same Python installations.

Why?

Most likely because you've installed a second Python 2.7 that doesn't include the obsolete `pythonw`, but Apple's pre-installed Python 2.7 definitely *does* include it.

The quickest way to check this is the `which` command. For example, on one of my machines:

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ which pythonw
/usr/bin/pythonw
```

That first one is a symlink to a Homebrew install of Python 2.7, while the second is Apple's Python 2.7. Your exact details may differ; the first one may be a symlink to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`, or a wrapper executable that actually lives in `/usr/local/bin`, or it may be in `/opt/local`, etc. The point is that they're not in the same directories.

At any rate, your two separate installations of Python don't share the same site-packages (and they shouldn't), so the fact that you've installed Flask for the second one doesn't help the Apple one. You can verify this by running them and printing out `sys.path`:

```
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', …]
>>> ^D
$ pythonw
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', …]
>>> ^D
```

---

Anyway, the simplest solution is to configure your editor to run `python` instead of `pythonw`—or, better, give it an absolute path to a Python interpreter like `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` to make absolutely sure you know what you're running.

(I don't know TextMate very well, but from [this source](https://github.com/textmate/python.tmbundle/blob/master/Commands/Run%20Script%20in%20Python.plist) it looks like it has a setting named `TM_PYTHON` that should control this…)

Comment: You're right. `python` was linking to a virtualenv `python` which was himself linking to the Homebrew `python` whereas `pythonw` was directly linking to the Homebrew `pythonw`. The reason is `pythonw` is not included in a directory when `virtualenv venv` and the purpose of virtualenv is precisely to isolate the packages even if the executables link to the same endpoint.

Comment: @Thibaud: Ah, I didn't think of virtualenv, because I've never set up an IDE to run with a virtualenv, but I can see how that would cause the problem. So, the details in my answer aren't actually correct; do you think I should edit it?

Comment: I did not mention virtualenv in my question, so your answer is perfectly fine because general enough to apply in both cases while precise enough to get me catch the problem.